# SUV bike rack questions

Tags: patentability, ep1582406a1

I have recently been interested in creating a "better" solution for transporting bikes within a vehicle, specifically an SUV. Without getting into details, I believe that I have designed a completely universal bike rack which would fit any SUV on the market today. It seems that someone had the same idea and has build/patented a design, that being said I have a few questions.

First of all, Google says the patent number is [ep1582406a1](http://www.google.com/patents/ep1582406a1). If you put this into google search you can see the document I have been viewing.

This patent number does not register in the US patent database, what does this mean?

Is this patent valid in the US even though it was filed in Germany?

My product is different in design but similar in function, should I be concerned?

Answer (score 2):

George beat me to the answer here.  He is correct (as usual).  Only granted and in-force US patents could be used to stop you in the US from making, using or selling a product.

There appears to be no [US Family Member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_family) of [ep1582406a1](http://www.google.com/patents/EP1582406A1?cl=en). However, [ep1582406a1](http://www.google.com/patents/EP1582406A1?cl=en) could constitute prior art for any patent applications you might file on your invention in the US.

Also, according to [Espacenet](http://worldwide.espacenet.com), patent [ep1582406a1](http://www.google.com/patents/EP1582406A1?cl=en) is ["deemed to be withdrawn"](http://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/guidelines/e/a_iii_11_3_4.htm) as of 2011, presumably due to the applicant not having paid maintenance fees.

---

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Patents are territorial. Only a granted and still in-force US patent can be used to stop you making, selling, using, offering for sale or importing in the US.